# iPhone App crashes on device with OS 3.1 not in simulator

Tags: iphone, crash, iphone-sdk-3.1, crash-reports

The app crashes on the tester's device (with OS 3.1) but does well on the simulator and my device with OS 3.0.

I have the crash log but I am finding it difficult to understand the reason of this crash as I cannot see the mentioned crashed thread (usually shown in a crash log).

What does this mean? "Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1"

Is there anyone who understands Crash Logs very well?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
Incident Identifier: EF273E16-AA9F-47CD-9587-8AC824F8DCB4
CrashReporter Key:   f3a4736dc8d450a3cb0ecb7367313dbbd816c484
Process:         MyApp [288]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/6664FF26-4DAE-4BF9-B243-6EF1C19E3062/MyApp_35.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2009-10-04 21:48:50.289 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1 (7C144)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.yourcompany.MyApp failed to terminate in time 
elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 4.100 (user 3.140, system 0.960), 68% CPU 
elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.770, 29% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080c4b8 0x3080b000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080f094 0x3080b000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3147a002 0x31423000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
4   CFNetwork                       0x31594302 0x3158f000 + 21250
5   Foundation                      0x3135d300 0x31328000 + 217856
6   MyApp                           0x00004232 -[MyAppAppDelegate logout] (MyAppAppDelegate.m:196)
7   MyApp                           0x00004396 -[MyAppAppDelegate applicationWillTerminate:] (MyAppAppDelegate.m:174)
8   UIKit                           0x331bf640 0x3314b000 + 476736
9   UIKit                           0x331ba824 0x3314b000 + 456740
10  UIKit                           0x331a1604 0x3314b000 + 353796
11  UIKit                           0x331a0634 0x3314b000 + 349748
12  UIKit                           0x331a008c 0x3314b000 + 348300
13  GraphicsServices                0x325339bc 0x3252e000 + 22972
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3147a524 0x31423000 + 357668
15  CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
16  GraphicsServices                0x325323a0 0x3252e000 + 17312
17  UIKit                           0x3314ec28 0x3314b000 + 15400
18  UIKit                           0x3314d228 0x3314b000 + 8744
19  MyApp                           0x00002090 main (main.m:13)
20  MyApp                           0x0000202c start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080c4b8 0x3080b000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080f094 0x3080b000 + 16532
2   QuartzCore                      0x3291c7bc 0x3290a000 + 75708
3   QuartzCore                      0x32915c70 0x3290a000 + 48240
4   QuartzCore                      0x3291546c 0x3290a000 + 46188
5   QuartzCore                      0x3291d5d4 0x3290a000 + 79316
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3143282a 0x31423000 + 63530
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3147a340 0x31423000 + 357184
8   CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
9   WebCore                         0x31e196f0 0x31d95000 + 542448
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080c4b8 0x3080b000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080f094 0x3080b000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3147a002 0x31423000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
4   Foundation                      0x31382998 0x31328000 + 371096
5   Foundation                      0x3137bac6 0x31328000 + 342726
6   Foundation                      0x31329d0e 0x31328000 + 7438
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308312f0 0x3080b000 + 156400
1   CoreFoundation                  0x314437e2 0x31423000 + 133090
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3089c720 0x3080b000 + 595744
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083e4d8 0x3080b000 + 210136
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083dc9c 0x3080b000 + 208028
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x3122c1c4 0x31225000 + 29124
4   WebCore                         0x32355104 0x31d95000 + 6029572
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3089c720 0x3080b000 + 595744
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083e4d8 0x3080b000 + 210136
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083dc9c 0x3080b000 + 208028
3   QuartzCore                      0x3299261c 0x3290a000 + 558620
4   QuartzCore                      0x329a5b8c 0x3290a000 + 637836
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x3cfff +MyApp armv6  <e899f2431af87ea5712324843883a131> /var/mobile/Applications/6664FF26-4DAE-4BF9-B243-6EF1C19E3062/MyApp_35.app/MyApp
   0xeb000 -    0xecfff  dns.so armv6  <957f94410f77a351749ac39d2b4b4abe> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv6  <c9ed2fd4b6ad0b603479d414cb382dd5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30005000 - 0x30011fff  CoreVideo armv6  <c31d33c7629e4f7b14a659f06f17674e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30061000 - 0x30078fff  OpenGLES armv6  <c31f4982bc65e67356e9b692f9976b1a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x30079000 - 0x301cdfff  AudioToolbox armv6  <065ac06f6e9f6bc62555565581a50637> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x30218000 - 0x30223fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <28bbad866f148b0d0adda83a01cec8f8> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3035d000 - 0x3040afff  ImageIO armv6  <8d44717aa7e4314848108d49b42ce576> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3040d000 - 0x30441fff  Security armv6  <36f9d8ca8c4e037e14edd6ae95524b24> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3045f000 - 0x30493fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <818346d31133d475739fe3c3b35b5bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30630000 - 0x30677fff  CoreMedia armv6  <07c13fb5ab31a52dfc3a50be02898f1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3067b000 - 0x30687fff  IAP armv6  <3752a21b994225b12069f929bf9b19d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x30725000 - 0x3072dfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <6673f222acee5f3a208169712387862a> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x307a9000 - 0x307b7fff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <c4d3d79ffaa7e13f556cd5f9c9fceff2> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x307b8000 - 0x30808fff  Celestial armv6  <6ccb9601cfba52fc5b7740e70fb565b4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x30809000 - 0x3080afff  CoreSurface armv6  <12f13b59faf0107d8536963b1552c481> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3080b000 - 0x30931fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <7bcb29dde047a859e6f57f2e9e63d38f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30986000 - 0x30988fff  ArtworkCache armv6  <49b8fea9eb3f6e7d2241d94cc241bbd2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x309f6000 - 0x309fbfff  ITSync armv6  <cad602d917d800f848e522d835c3a031> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30b45000 - 0x30b4bfff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <74ead45f4f6840457b982e3a5cc30055> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30b4d000 - 0x30b79fff  CoreLocation armv6  <ac2b8ebbcb03f7a57c61c9a5eaa5b3d7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x30b7e000 - 0x30bbcfff  VideoToolbox armv6  <15ea0e25a764b445ce59401f09c2787d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30bbd000 - 0x30cd3fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <4930d982e746b906ca6fac74e30d361b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x30ef7000 - 0x30f16fff  Bom armv6  <fcd9e839c0d1a25cbf59a08cc60fea3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30f1a000 - 0x30f1cfff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <db3c3a983db3d53f6199dafb8b472bfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x31043000 - 0x3112afff  MusicLibrary armv6  <3deebbf46222551b71d0121b6360308b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x31196000 - 0x3119afff  libgermantok.dylib armv6  <de2afc812c51de295be8f32b73dcb77d> /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
0x311ac000 - 0x31221fff  MediaPlayer armv6  <8e2efee9a7b8abcfddec740e95c87ed3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x31225000 - 0x31322fff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <303af93622bcb0c4b68ed62b55d124fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31328000 - 0x31420fff  Foundation armv6  <8ddca22a76a5f2bc91f55c87eea8e9a5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31423000 - 0x314cffff  CoreFoundation armv6  <a40c65b893c6ca5c0b632d2804ad59d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x314fc000 - 0x31556fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <e346522412f1e957d9cee6511c66bdc9> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x31557000 - 0x31557fff  vecLib armv6  <c8a08b45effd5eb35a476a969628e52d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31558000 - 0x3155bfff  MobileInstallation armv6  <e9617b1538fe22f2d6eb91156d130409> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3158f000 - 0x315fcfff  CFNetwork armv6  <19088cf3f0b4f667b52482ac6ab99690> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31603000 - 0x3160dfff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <8c6d9927c48ad08cfae540d60af17b6a> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x3160e000 - 0x31617fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <a2849d569ba1e7a4083aec5be693f055> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31622000 - 0x3165ffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <640dc156b068d347f6c83a27adad6d06> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31660000 - 0x3169efff  CoreText armv6  <c21aa763bf62e82e8a1f062c3e201e84> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x316ac000 - 0x316bcfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <f1b3998fcf7b60cee74b3e03fc94bf31> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x316f7000 - 0x31703fff  DataDetectorsCore armv6  <b9c577725d045e68e3b485a0513a95dc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x317c5000 - 0x31872fff  WebKit armv6  <b555f14fc6c288f8725843055d936507> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31933000 - 0x3193afff  WebUI armv6  <0426244613c88091f61c8a056285da5d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x31d2b000 - 0x31d2bfff  Accelerate armv6  <21e1dc9fad96f0d51afbeb7f7e006aaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31d95000 - 0x324e8fff  WebCore armv6  <28b391254b0edba93084f458e5805787> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x324f7000 - 0x3251efff  AppSupport armv6  <d8d247ecb9f5a3ff92583048a5da264c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3252e000 - 0x32539fff  GraphicsServices armv6  <8629b6affa7c7752ab3c702f1c694325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x325f8000 - 0x326eefff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <893355592f660060653383b29f42d102> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x326ef000 - 0x32729fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <cf9cc6079374718dce29cba9de48b993> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32848000 - 0x32895fff  IOKit armv6  <035ec9372089422af1ccdb17d72ac091> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x328da000 - 0x328e9fff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <6d87ea09ffe173f3d356514e7382bd95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3290a000 - 0x329b4fff  QuartzCore armv6  <cb65d19d96053b411b9a1c68f8f20a33> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x329d6000 - 0x329f4fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <e2f1ba98b2a7b91e91896cea1db932e4> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x32a02000 - 0x32a2cfff  MobileQuickLook armv6  <98be398458dd7bc7faa3e9f21095b744> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileQuickLook.framework/MobileQuickLook
0x32a2d000 - 0x32be7fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <58e0bf5baaceb205917d03050a0ac954> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32cee000 - 0x32d58fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <1982380fa8b60e63fd29559efb58d1f0> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x32d59000 - 0x32d5afff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <436a03767758117cc9ecec8417f2d185> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32eb0000 - 0x32eb7fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <faaee75832afeaf9d352318edd62970b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x32eb8000 - 0x32ef2fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <56a514c096120e8a1e1bb52b8645699b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x330ce000 - 0x330f1fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <5e02a84096d714b4f8a38aa8f4107b85> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33110000 - 0x33148fff  TextInput armv6  <a13cc5ea542bf5d4a66256e1c7ca0cee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x33149000 - 0x3314afff  liblangid.dylib armv6  <232d2e6eb6afe91ca61aaac4d37009e5> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3314b000 - 0x33f3cfff  UIKit armv6  <dfcffbbb1e8813d91fe5fd5daf69ed11> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33f74000 - 0x33fd5fff  GMM armv6  <45ce64a42afbb59806bf588439b4bfc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x33fda000 - 0x33fe4fff  DataDetectorsUI armv6  <d730977336f18295ddd6167cbe157a9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x33fe5000 - 0x34040fff  CoreAudio armv6  <92290f4dba14837427eaa399a55929cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34150000 - 0x34156fff  MBX2D armv6  <0e5d686d0e641a8efc5dc2003c37e2f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x34170000 - 0x3418efff  AddressBook armv6  <d221b21a3d8594abc8ee717ae6f77076> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x3419b000 - 0x341a5fff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <48254d8d389dc9ecf90688e227ddba1a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x341f0000 - 0x341f4fff  IOSurface armv6  <1b951baaae45efbbae825b670612f478> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x341f5000 - 0x342f6fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <aceb70042ae76cfec9838f6771db48d8> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3430a000 - 0x343adfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <c3df9efc40404bc1865caacbf6209a1e> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like your app took too much time to quit.

Comment: Yeah I found the solution. By looking into "Exception Code:0x8badf00d" aka "bad food", I found out that my app is taking too much time to quit.

In case any one is interested to view Apple documentation about it, here's the link:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html#ACQUIRING_CRASH_REPORTS